# Portable WAMP package?

Tags: wamp

is there anyway that i can use PHP, mySQL, apache, phpmyadmin on a USB on a windows 7 computer? Reason for asking is that I don't have enough rights to install packages like XAMPP on a computer and i want to test some php code files.
Thanks.

Comment: PortableApps has a portable version of XAMPP - http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp

Comment: This is an old question, but to anyone else seeing this, check out Uniform Server at [http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/) It runs a full wamp stack on a USB stick as a program or service.

Comment: You can try a similar project called Neard : https://github.com/crazy-max/neard

Comment: @CrazyMax nerd has system dependency:
"
    Windows XP SP3 or later.
    WSH (Windows Script Host) : Open a command prompt and type wscript to check.
    SETX : Open a command prompt and type setx /? to check.
***Be Admin user.***
    Download and install the latest Neard Prerequisites Package."

Comment: @Mohammad Like others

Answer (score 14):

A few years forward...Try uWamp http://www.uwamp.com/en/
It's light-weight and doesn't need installation, therefore it can run from flashdrive.

Comment: uwamp has system dependency:
"Before use UwAmp you must install Visual C++ Redistributable x86 version vc_redist.x86.exe."

Comment: I think you can put the required dll files next to the main executable and be fine even if the system lacks it

Answer (score 2):

[USBWebserver](https://www.usbwebserver.net/webserver/) is discontinued but i'm still using it

Comment: At present this has quite a price tag $160.00 .