# How to resolve the issue in running wampserver from USB flash drive?

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I'm using Windows 7 on my system. I'm trying to run wampserver remotely on a USB flash drive. For that I did necessary path configuration settings and moved the whole installation folder of wamp from my machine to USB flash drive. 
I referred the following link for migration of wamp from local machine to USB flash drive:`http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,62431,62812`

After performing all the necessary steps, I double click wampmanager.exe in wamp folder, the red coloured wamp symbol "W" get appear in the system tray. It's not getting converted to Green "W" which means wampserver has not been started. 
For detecting the issue I checked the port 80 availability, it's available. When I clicked Apache->Service->Start?Resume Service, I get a dialog box titled "Aestan Tray Menu" containing the message "Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not perform service action: The system cannot find the file specified". I googled it for the solution, but couldn't get it. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903966/portable-wamp-package>

Comment: I've used [uwAmp](http://www.uwamp.com/) for a portable wamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'v forgot some file when you moved all the server to the flash memory. There is a version specific for flash memory (portable version) called 'Uniform Server'.

There is the link to the author webpage.
http://www.uniformserver.com

It's totally free of charge.
Greetings!

Comment: As per your suggestion I tried Uniform Server. Now it's up and running from USB, but giving problem in database connectivity giving error "Error in Connection". I couldn't get the reason behind it. Can you help me to solve this one? Following is my database connectivity code :
<?php
 class data
{
function data(){

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error in Connection");
mysql_select_db("XYZ",$conn) or die("Problem in selecting Database");
}
public function querySend($query)
{
$result=mysql_query($query);
return $result;
}
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

The error warning in Wamp is vague but I think you will find Wamp is simply looking in the wrong place.

Remember `localhost` is the root on all devices so `wamp` will look for the instance of `localhost`.

Perhaps to avoid confusion you should call `"localhost"` on the `usb` something unique.

See this post on renaming "localhost"
[How to change the URL from "localhost" to something else, on a local system using wampserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652373/how-to-change-the-url-from-localhost-to-something-else-on-a-local-system-usin)

Comment: Did you try to add a link. It's not visible