# How to change the URL from "localhost" to something else, on a local system using wampserver?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, localhost, wampserver

On a Windows machine, there's a system running on the local wampserver, but while the application is running on localhost, the URL says otherwise.

While I would expect the URL to be like this based on the directory structure:

```
http://localhost/pro/include/db_report.php
```

The developer has managed to do this:

```
http://ap-mispro/pro/include/db_report.php
```

So instead of `localhost`, the URL says `ap-mispro`.

And both URLs work fine.

How is the second URL made? I tried checking out the `wampmanager.ini` and `wampmanager.tpl` but maybe I didn't know what to look for?

Answer (score 62):

### WINDOWS + WAMP solution

**Step 1** 
Go to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\` 
open `httpd.conf` file and change 
`#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` 
to
 `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` 
i.e. uncomment the line so that it can includes the virtual hosts file.

**Step 2**
Go to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra` 
and open `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and add the following code

```
<VirtualHost myWebsite.local>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myWebsite/"
    ServerName myWebsite.local
    ServerAlias myWebsite.local
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/myWebsite/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

change `myWebsite.local` and `C:/wamp/www/myWebsite/` as per your requirements.

**Step 3** 
Open `hosts` file in `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/` and add the following line ( Don't delete anything )

```
127.0.0.1 myWebsite.local
```

change `myWebsite.local` as per your name requirements

**Step 4**
restart your server. That's it

---

### WINDOWS + XAMPP solution

Same steps as that of WAMP just change the paths according to XAMPP which corresponds to path in WAMP

Comment: Is there any short method to do this for all project in www folder

Comment: Messing up with a quite old answer here, but can't resist. On later versions of Wamp and Windows, You may have to [enable mod rewrite](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very useful!

Comment: Easier way is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839362/virtual-host-using-wamp-is-not-working/47863472#47863472

Comment: Good explanation!. But I am not able to access the website on my local network. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Hkachhia disable your internet and try, sometimes dns problem

Comment: What would happen if I rename it is as mywebsite.com?

Answer (score 28):

Copy the `hosts` file and add `127.0.0.1` and name which you want to show or run at the browser link. For example:

```
127.0.0.1   abc
```

Then run `abc/` as a local host in the browser.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

They are probably using a virtual host (http://www.keanei.com/2011/07/14/creating-virtual-hosts-with-wamp/)

You can go into your Apache configuration file (httpd.conf) or your virtual host configuration file (recommended) and add something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/ap-mispro
    ServerName ap-mispro

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

And when you call up `http://ap-mispro/` you would see whatever is in C:/wamp/www/ap-mispro (assuming default directory structure). The ServerName and DocumentRoot do no have to have the same name at all. Other factors needed to make this work:

1. You have to make sure httpd-vhosts.conf is included by httpd.conf for your changes in that file to take effect.
2. When you make changes to either file, you have to restart Apache to see your changes.
3. You have to change your hosts file
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) for your computer to know
   where to go when you type `http://ap-mispro` into your browser. This
   change to your hosts file will only apply to your computer - not
   that it sounds like you are trying from anyone else's.

There are plenty more things to know about virtual hosts but this should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

please refer http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name

this is best solution ever

Comment: Hey, as it stands, this is a [link-only answer and is susceptible to rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/174440). Please consider adding relevant text from the linked resource into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

for new version of Wamp

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.local
  DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/domain/
  <Directory "C:/wamp/www/domain/">
      Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

After another hour or two I can actually answer my own question.

Someone on another forum mentioned that you need to keep a mention of plain ol' localhost in the httpd-vhost.conf file, so here's what I ended up with in there:

```
ServerName localhost

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
```

```
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/pocket/"
ServerName pocket.clickng.com
ServerAlias pocket.clickng.com
ErrorLog "logs/pocket.clickng.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/pocket.clickng.com-access.log" common
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/pocket/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Exit WAMP, restart - good to go. Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and open hosts file and add
this

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
127.0.0.1    www.example.com
```

then  go to  C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra open httpd-ajp.conf file and add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/pojectroot"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectroot">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

### WINDOWS + MAMP solution

**Step 1** 
Go to `S:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\` 
open `httpd.conf` file and change

`#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

to

`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` 
i.e. uncomment the line so that it can includes the virtual hosts file.

**Step 2**
Go to `S:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\extra` 
and open `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and add the following code

```
<VirtualHost myWebsite.local>
    DocumentRoot "S:\MAMP\htdocs/myWebsite/"
    ServerName myWebsite.local
    ServerAlias myWebsite.local
    <Directory "S:\MAMP\htdocsmyWebsite/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

change `myWebsite.local` and `S:\MAMP\htdocs/myWebsite/` as per your requirements.

**Step 3** 
Open `hosts` file in `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/` and add the following line ( Don't delete anything )

```
127.0.0.1 myWebsite.local
```

change `myWebsite.local` as per your name requirements

**Step 4**
restart your server. That's it

---

Answer (score 0):

**This method will work for xamp/wamp/lamp**

1. 1st go to your server directory, for example, C:\xamp
2. 2nd go to apache/conf/extra and open httpd-vhosts.conf
3. 3rd add following code to this file

> ```
>  <VirtualHost myWebsite.local>
>         DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/php-bugs/"
>         ServerName php-bugs.local
>         ServerAlias php-bugs.local
>         <Directory "C:/wamp/www/php-bugs/">
>             Order allow,deny
>             Allow from all
>         </Directory>
>     </VirtualHost>
> ```

*For DocumentRoot and Directory add your local directory 
 For ServerName and ServerAlias give your server a name*

4. Finally go to C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc and open hosts file
   add `127.0.0.1 php-bugs.local` and nothing else
5. For the finishing touch restart your server

   For Multile local domain  add another section of code into httpd-vhosts.conf

> ```
>  <VirtualHost myWebsite.local>
>         DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/php-bugs2/"
>         ServerName php-bugs.local2
>         ServerAlias php-bugs.local2
>         <Directory "C:/wamp/www/php-bugs2/">
>             Order allow,deny
>             Allow from all
>         </Directory>
>     </VirtualHost>
> ```

and add your host into host file `127.0.0.1 php-bugs.local2`