# How to set mydomain.com locally in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel, and I have installed a fresh copy of laravel. My project root directory is located in `E:/xampp/htdocs/myapp` and I want this to load on myapp.com in browser how exactly to do this ? I am using laravel 5.2 and xampp for my project.

Comment: read about virtual host

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the URL from "localhost" to something else, on a local system using wampserver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652373/how-to-change-the-url-from-localhost-to-something-else-on-a-local-system-usin)

Comment: It is not question about Laravel, it is about setting up domain names on local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with enabling virtual host on your xampp settings. First of all you need to visit `E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\https-vhosts.conf` and make some edits. Edit httpd-vhosts.conf file in your favorite editor and add the below code at end of the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/yourprojectfolder/public"
    ServerName yourdesirename.com
</VirtualHost>
```

After this you need open notepad as administrator and edit hosts file

> (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

**Note :** If hosts file is not showing in the target directory you need to change the select box to 'Show All Files'

and add `127.0.0.1  localhost yourdesirename.com` at the end of hosts file, once done now open your browser and type `yourdesirename.com` and your project will dance live there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Laravel 5.2 [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/valet) is a pretty nice tool.