# Laravel 5 .htaccess url public remove not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am using laravel 5 with default directory structure.
For removing public folder from url I am using following code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using xampp and my path is like this http://localhost/pro/laravel5/public

so my project is in htdocs/pro/laravel5/ here I have kept above .htaccess
else everything is default

when I try to access my project I get following error.

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 145
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 719
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 210
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

How can I solve this any suggestion, am I missing any things in .htaccess let me know.
And I don't want to use second option of moving files and folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey any way you have to copy **.htaccess** and **index** file to your root path then  in your htaccess file use **public**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

then your **index.php** thtz all :)

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel5/bootstrap/autoload.php'; and
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel5/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: hey move .htaccess, index and web.config files your project path and change the way i mention above i tried for you its working for me

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is

Rename the `server.php` in the your Laravel Project Root folder to `index.php`

Copy the .htaccess file from `/public` directory to your Laravel root folder.

And that's it now your project will be live in your browser like `pro/laravel5/`

Comment: trying this option css path is not proper using asset function.

Comment: css path will work, you have to link it correctly. Put all your assets in Public folder and then link it via {{asset('yourCss.css')}}

Comment: hey Iftikhar uddin, sorry you get down vote but I didn't do it. I am using asset function only but it is not taking proper path.

Comment: @user2293790 no i am not saying to you. Can you share the code with us so that i can get idea what is wrong there ?

Comment: @user2293790 i will suggest you to use virtual hosts which is the best option laravel have. Here is it take a look ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879645/how-to-set-mydomain-com-locally-in-laravel/37879807#37879807 )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118536/discussion-between-iftikhar-uddin-and-user2293790).