# PDF edit in angular 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-forms, hapi.js

I'm facing CORS issue in node version v8.9.4.
Error is -

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed 
access.
```

At front end i'm using angular4 and have placed below code in my headers, but still facing issue.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, 
OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-
Token');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is Chrome bug/issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

You will have to either

- Use another browser for testing
- edit hosts file to assign [localhost to some pseudo-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36601164/607407) of your choice
- test directly from your (or another real) site, instead of on localhost

Comment: I've tried on chrome, firefox, safari, its not working on any of them.

Comment: And the error is the same? Did you check if those headers are actually sent? You can do that by inspecting the requests in network tab of the dev tools.