# Turn localhost in nodejs work as servername

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i just started full stack.
I have a server pysically , i want to put my code on it and run the nodejs server from it so when people want to get my site they will http://computer_name or http://computer_ip and not localhost:port    (which work on my computer only..) 
*the server is on a private domain which cannot access the ISP(so deploying my website isnt an option)

Comment: what have you tried so far? just copy your code to your server and start it with `node myfile.js`. this will work. assuming you choose port `80` you don't have to type the port. what you want is essentially to deploy your code, but on your own server. then you probably want something like a windows service or systemd unit to keep your node server running. Depending on your os. maybe a reverse proxy in front. Try to search the web a bit for this, and then try to describe your *exact* problem so people can help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652373/how-to-change-the-url-from-localhost-to-something-else-on-a-local-system-usin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fastest way to get you started.
Locate the **`hosts`** file on your machine:
***C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc***

Open that file as an administrator using something like Notepad.exe ...
At the very end you'll see this lines:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#   127.0.0.1       mySuperNodeApp.com
```

Here you can add your favorite domain name with the same IP address, eg mySuperNodeApp.com with the IP of 127.0.0.1.

---

There're other ways to achieve this, eg using **Wamp Server Tools:**

To change your `localhost` to domain name all you need to do is run your **wamp server** and go to localhost page.

On the `localhost` page, on the tool section, click on ***Add A Virtual Host*** then you will be guided to the page where you'll see 3 input fields:
a) First is the place where you enter your `yourDomainName`, 
b) The second input field is optional; you can add an IP address, or leave it empty,
c) The third input field goes to the address of wamp server which is common as below:
*`C:/wamp64/www`*   or  *`C:/wamp/www/`*

Once you are done with the above steps, click on the Start --[the creation of the virtual host].

Then go to wamp and `rightclick` -> `tool` -> `restartDNS`.
Now open your browser and type your domain name to open the localhost page.