# Docker compose network not resolving hostname in javascript http request

Tags: javascript, docker-compose, request

I am currently writing a small fullstack application using Docker compose, vue, and python. All my containers work in isolation, but I can't seem to get my containers to communicate using host names... Here's my code:

Docker Compose

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: ./TranscriptionFrontend
    ports:
     - 4998:4998
  api:
    build: ./TranscriptionAPI
```

Javascript Frontend Request

```js
fetch("http://api:4999/transcribe", {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(res => {
        res.json().then((json_obj) =>{
          this.transcription_result = json_obj['whisper-response']
        })
      }).catch(e => {
        this.transcription_result = "Error communicating with api: " + e;
      })
```

I know my API service works because originally I was just mapping it to a port on my localhost, but that got messy and I want to keep access to it within my docker container. In all cases the host name could not be resolved from my JS request. Also, curl-ing from my containers using host names does provide a response i.e. `docker-compose exec web curl api` or vice versa. I'm a beginner to java script and docker so apologies if I'm missing something basic.

What I've tried:

- XML Http Request
- Making call without using `http://`

Answer (score 1):

Host names for docker container communication are only possible if you define a `user defined bridge network`. Here's an example:

(On your docker-compose.yml)

```
...
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#:%7E:text=Using%20a%20user%2Ddefined%20network,defined%20networks%20on%20the%20fly.)'s a link to the Docker docs just in case. Let me know if this helped!

Comment: From what I've understood, isn't that created automatically as a build condition for my docker compose? When I run `docker network ls`, I see a bridge network titled `transcriptionapp_default` with my web and api containers attached according to docker inspect.

Comment: A bridge network is created by default, but it won't allow you to reference containers by name. In order to do that, it needs to be user defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker service name won't reflect in the url unless you configure some virtual hosts that points to its image on localhost.
You can look into something like [How to change the URL from "localhost" to something else, on a local system using wampserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652373/how-to-change-the-url-from-localhost-to-something-else-on-a-local-system-usin) if that is what you really want to do but I feel it might be defeating the point.

My approach would be to pass the API url as environment variable to your front-end service directly in the Docker compose file. Something like:

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./TranscriptionFrontend
    ports:
     - 4998:4998
    environment:
      API_URL: http://127.0.0.1:4999
  api:
    build: ./TranscriptionAPI
    ports:
     - 4999:4999
```

and then inject the env variable into your Javascript app build.
For example assuming you're using any Node.js stack for compiling your JS you could have it as a `process.env` property and then do:

```
fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/transcribe`, { ... })
```

Comment: Okay, that's what I was doing originally. I just wanted to dumb it down to one exposed port per application because I have many containers that I don't want clutter my ports. In addition, I'm not sure how it would effect scaling... What would you recommend?

Comment: Well this way you still have only one exposed port per application/service. It might be a lot of ports locally, but when it comes to deploying to production each service can (should?) have its own environment (server or storage depending on the nature of the service/application)
In terms of scalability, I believe independent micro-services are key, so much easier to maintain and debug should something go wrong in one of them.